# I've "bound" an entire IPv6 /64 - now how do I get my kernel to respond to ARP to accept packets?

Tags: kernel-modules, routing, ipv6

I'm on CentOS 8 stream. My IP is 2001:570:1:b86::12, and I ran this:-

```
 ip -6 route add local 2001:570:1:b86::/64 dev lo
```

and built and ran one of [these](https://www.potaroo.net/ispcol/2016-09/), and i can now connect (locally) to my server on any of those 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 IP addresses and it all works.  I can also connect from a remote machine to the existing 2001:570:1:b86::12 and it works fine over the interne
t as well.

However, I cannot connect from remote to any other of my IPs...

```
$ ping6 -c 1 2001:570:1:b86:1234:2345:3456:6789
PING6(56=40+8+8 bytes) 2001:8000:1ced:6d00:f507:cb71:703f:afe1 --> 2001:570:1:b86:1234:2345:3456:6789

--- 2001:570:1:b86:1234:2345:3456:6789 ping6 statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss
```

And looking with this, my box doesn't appear to be replying to the ARP ?

```
# tcpdump -i eno1 -n -nn -vvv -XX proto 58
dropped privs to tcpdump
tcpdump: listening on eno1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
00:11:47.354817 IP6 (class 0xc0, hlim 255, next-header ICMPv6 (58) payload length: 32) fe80::629c:9fff:fe86:c00 > ff02::1:ff56:6789: [icmp6 sum ok] ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, length 32, who has 2001:570:1:b86:1234:2345:3456:6789
          source link-address option (1), length 8 (1): 60:9c:9f:86:0c:00
            0x0000:  609c 9f86 0c00
        0x0000:  3333 ff56 6789 609c 9f86 0c00 86dd 6c00  33.Vg.`.......l.
        0x0010:  0000 0020 3aff fe80 0000 0000 0000 629c  ....:.........b.
        0x0020:  9fff fe86 0c00 ff02 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
        0x0030:  0001 ff56 6789 8700 f8a7 0000 0000 2001  ...Vg...........
        0x0040:  0570 0001 0b86 1234 2345 3456 6789 0101  .p.....4#E4Vg...
        0x0050:  609c 9f86 0c00                           `.....
00:11:48.389831 IP6 (class 0xc0, hlim 255, next-header ICMPv6 (58) payload length: 32) fe80::629c:9fff:fe86:c00 > ff02::1:ff56:6789: [icmp6 sum ok] ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, length 32, who has 2001:570:1:b86:1234:2345:3456:6789
          source link-address option (1), length 8 (1): 60:9c:9f:86:0c:00
            0x0000:  609c 9f86 0c00
        0x0000:  3333 ff56 6789 609c 9f86 0c00 86dd 6c00  33.Vg.`.......l.
        0x0010:  0000 0020 3aff fe80 0000 0000 0000 629c  ....:.........b.
        0x0020:  9fff fe86 0c00 ff02 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
        0x0030:  0001 ff56 6789 8700 f8a7 0000 0000 2001  ...Vg...........
        0x0040:  0570 0001 0b86 1234 2345 3456 6789 0101  .p.....4#E4Vg...
        0x0050:  609c 9f86 0c00                           `.....
00:11:49.386308 IP6 (class 0xc0, hlim 255, next-header ICMPv6 (58) payload length: 32) fe80::629c:9fff:fe86:c00 > ff02::1:ff56:6789: [icmp6 sum ok] ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, length 32, who has 2001:570:1:b86:1234:2345:3456:6789
          source link-address option (1), length 8 (1): 60:9c:9f:86:0c:00
            0x0000:  609c 9f86 0c00
        0x0000:  3333 ff56 6789 609c 9f86 0c00 86dd 6c00  33.Vg.`.......l.
        0x0010:  0000 0020 3aff fe80 0000 0000 0000 629c  ....:.........b.
        0x0020:  9fff fe86 0c00 ff02 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
        0x0030:  0001 ff56 6789 8700 f8a7 0000 0000 2001  ...Vg...........
        0x0040:  0570 0001 0b86 1234 2345 3456 6789 0101  .p.....4#E4Vg...
        0x0050:  609c 9f86 0c00                           `.....
```

How do I tell the kernel to instruct the router that my box is the one that accepts those packets?

If this is something to do with tproxy, I do have that (not sure what to do in my firewall to get those ARPs working though)

```
# lsmod | grep tproxy
nf_tproxy_ipv6         16384  0
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OP's method is [possible since Linux 2.6.37](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/?h=linux-2.6.37.y&id=ab79ad14a2d51e95f0ac3cef7cd116a57089ba82), but requires additional settings.

The IPv6 equivalent for ARP is [NDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbor_Discovery_Protocol) (which is using ICMPv6 multicast/unicast instead of ARP's dedicated L2 protocol with broadcast/unicast).

[`proxy_ndp`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt?h=v4.18#n1483) doesn't behave exactly as Proxy ARP here (it still requires per-IP settings, which we don't want here) and won't help. Instead a dedicated daemon called [`ndppd`](https://github.com/DanielAdolfsson/ndppd/blob/master/README.md) which listens to NDP requests to (usually) answer on behalf of other systems can manage this case. It must be set to not attempt to query a backend system before answering, since there is no such other system.

Assuming here that:

- main interface is called `eth0`
- system is alone in this /64 (except *possibly* an optional global address for its router).
- system isn't supposed to be set as router. See minor caveat.

Enable EPEL (package `epel-release`), install `ndppd`, and use a configuration similar to this one in `/etc/ndppd.conf`:

```
proxy eth0 {
    router no
    rule 2001:570:1:b86::/64 {
        static
    }
}
```

`static` makes the daemon answer immediately without querying any backend system, which is what has to be done for this case, since all addresses belong to (or more exactly here, all queries should reach) the host.

Caveats:

- `ndppd` will generate a warning when starting because the netmask is large.

  This matters when the system's router wasn't explicitly set up for routing this /64 block via 2001:570:1:b86::12 or (much better) via the link local address on system's `eth0` interface.

  If a network scan from remote is done on the block without the router properly set up, this router would allocate an NDP entry for each new address seen in this /64 scan. Small (home) routers not designed to be robust and evict old entries fast enough might not cope well with this and go into out of memory/high CPU use conditions (ie: [DoS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack)).
- since the actual host's IPv6 address is among the /64, querying this address will elicit two NDP answers: one by the kernel and one by `ndppd`. If the system is actually a router this could cause intermittent routing issues. In such case `router yes` could be pondered. `ndppd`'s configuration doesn't appear to have a subnet override a larger network including this subnet, like would happen in a routing table.

Comment: `nf_tproxy_ipv6` would be for transparent traffic interception, but OP never hinted such interception should happen.  Correct route and iptables/nftables settings are described there (but there's no IPv6 example): https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/tproxy.txt . Can't tell if the NDP setup in this answer has to be used then, but I suspect it should.

Comment: Works, although exhibits some strange behavior: the "first ping" is dropped (so doing "ping -c 1" always fails). The next question is what to do next if our 24port MicroTik CSS326-24G-2S+ blows up on a scan... it's my only way in to my boxes... FWIW - this is not for a proxy; my box handles the traffic itself.

Comment: Actually if your (microtik) router was set to route the whole subnet through one (link-local) IPv6 address on CentOS8, 1/ no risk of DoS 2/ this whole answer isn't needed and the setup would be simplified. No more need of ndppd.